# Vue-if conditional not working. if-Else block appears to be skipped

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

This is a follow up question to one I posted here: ([I have 2 records in a database Vue outputs 8 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371668/i-have-2-records-in-a-database-vue-outputs-8-records/41371853?noredirect=1#comment69982993_41371853)). In that question, was having trouble fetching a JSON list of games for an online casino I'm building. In my original question, Vue was unable to load the JSON as JSON, but now that's fixed.

I am now trying to parse this JSON using Vue to loop through all of the games in the games array and print either `In progress` or `Game is joinable`. However, instead of getting 8 different records from the database (from a weird response array object returned by `this.$http.get`. I now see that my JSON list is seemly being ignored by my Vue template; none of the objects in the collection get outputted (again  either `In progress` or `Joinable`. I just get a blank list.

Is my v-if conditional programmed correctly? I checked the documentation and everything seems to be set up correctly. I find it odd that neither the v-if, or v-else, divs> are executed.

vuewgames.blade.php

```
@extends('app')


@section('content')
    <strong>Below is a list of joinable games</strong>
    <div class="container">
    <games></games>
    </div>

  <div id="games-list">
      <template id="games-template">



          <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" v-for="game in games">
                     <strong>play against @{{ game.player1 }}</strong>
              </li>



          </ul>

            <pre>@{{ games | json }}</pre>

      </template>


  </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
@endsection
```

all.js

```
Vue.component('games', {
    template: '#games-template',


    data: function() {
        return {

            games: []


        };



    },


    created: function () {

        var self = this;

        this.$http.get('/api/games').then(function (response) {
            // fetch array from jsoN object

            response.json().then(function (games) {
                console.log(games);
            });

        });
    },

});




new Vue({
    el: 'body'


});
```

Comment: Does `game.player1` render properly if `v-if` is omitted? Just wondering if `game.ready` is being misinterpreted.

Comment: I took out the v-if condition completely, and I do not see player1's ID display in the list. I see a null variable being putputted. I think the JSON output is being parsed. When I look at the object in Google Chrome Dev,s tools, I see a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you're not getting the information to the instance is due to scope.

When you're using closures in javascript the scope of the `this` isn't the containing object.

One way to get around this is to assign `this` to another variable outside of the function and then use that instead. You should be able to get it working by changing your `created` method to be:

```
created: function () {

    var self = this;

    this.$http.get('/api/games').then(function (response) {
        // fetch array from jsoN object

        response.json().then(function (games) {
            self.games = games;
        });

    });
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for youre answer, but now when i try to view the page, in my Chrome DevTools, I get a [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "game.player1": TypeError: Cannot read property 'player1' of undefined (found in component: <games>).

Comment: @TomMorison In that case can you edit your question to show what you are getting if you do `console.log(games)` inside your `response.json()` function? Also, you might find this usful: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I get in DevTools https://s29.postimg.org/mjgqv4rlj/Screen_Shot_2016_12_30_at_4_51_51_PM.png

Comment: Ok, next one. Comment out the entire `<ul>...</ul>` and add in `<pre>@{{ games | json }}</pre>`. What do you get?

Comment: I just get an empty array. When I visit api/games in the browser, I get my JSON output.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If it is just showing an empty array then it wouldn't ever start the loop so you'd never see the "in progress" message or get the error...

Comment: I made some changes to the code since I originally asked my question. I have updated my code in my question. I now do not get anythig when  I iteratee through my list (I just added that code back in). I've added my updated code.

Comment: Success. i just added self.games = games to my response function and everything works! Thanks

Comment: @TomMorison Glad you got it working! Would you mind accepting the answer if it helped you?